# How do I disable 'Warning: Unsafe Paste' pop-up?

Tags: 20.04, paste

After upgrading from xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I'm getting the following warning message popping up when I try to paste into a terminal:

[image: Warning: Unsafe Paste]

I'm and experienced user. I *do* understand the implications of pasting arbitrary text from a web page into the terminal, including the possibility of the page injecting invisible text into the clipboard. When I'm pasting text from a web page, I explicitly paste it into a text editor. Every time. I understand why this message exists, and why it shouldn't be easy to disable, but I *do* take my own precautions, and I *don't* want this message.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: This has got to be the biggest and stupidest anti-feature of all time!

Comment: @carlspring: I don't think that it's stupid -- users who aren't being careful about their pastes could *definitely* get pwned. The implementation is clunky and I don't want it in *my* way, but it's better than having a lot of new users get compromised out of ignorance.

Comment: Users who aren't careful and don't know what they're doing, should probably not use Linux or any form of Unix, as it requires a certain level of understanding and caution. Turning Ubuntu into just another form of Windows is not what Linux is meant for. I mean -- how would this functionality help someone who doesn't understand what `sudo rm -rf /` does?

Comment: @carlspring: I knew what `sudo rm -rf /` does *long* before I understood that pasting what *looks* like `ls -l ~` could actually inject hidden malicious commands into the command line. In any case, you don't become an experienced unix user without being an inexperienced unix user first.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Open up the terminal, click on edit, click on preferences, and untick the box.

[image: Here you go.]

That should do it.